# rails 4 cannot create model

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Model definition

```
class Connection < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :user, :user2, :message_id, :send, :receive
end
```

When I tried to

```
Connection.create(:user =>1,:user2=>2,:message_id => 5,:send => true,:receive => false)
```

I got error

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 0)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/read.rb:53:in `__temp__3756e646'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:330:in `clone_attribute_value'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:65:in `write_attribute'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/write.rb:19:in `__temp__57375627='
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:42:in `public_send'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:42:in `_assign_attribute'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/protected_attributes-1.0.3/lib/active_record/mass_assignment_security/attribute_assignment.rb:67:in `block in assign_attributes'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/protected_attributes-1.0.3/lib/active_record/mass_assignment_security/attribute_assignment.rb:61:in `each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/protected_attributes-1.0.3/lib/active_record/mass_assignment_security/attribute_assignment.rb:61:in `assign_attributes'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/protected_attributes-1.0.3/lib/active_record/mass_assignment_security/core.rb:16:in `initialize'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:27:in `new'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:27:in `new'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/protected_attributes-1.0.3/lib/active_record/mass_assignment_security/persistence.rb:45:in `create'
    from (irb):3
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:64:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
```

What is going on here?

Comment: Your stacktrace isn't complete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`send` is a Ruby Kernel method used to [dynamically invoke methods on Ruby objects](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Object.html#method-i-send), which is used heavily within ActiveRecord (among other places). `attr_accessible` is overriding the `send` method with a different implementation within your model objects!

Try using a different name for that attribute.

Comment: Right, `send` isn't exactly the best choice for an attribute name. But, as always, hindsight is 20-20. Might want to user `user_id` and `user2_id` (or better, `to_user_id` and `from_user_id`) instead of `user` and `user2` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts:

1. Try writing out your hash like this Favorite.create(user_id: current_user.id, video_id: @video.id, my_third_property: "value")
2. For debugging purposes try using [MODEL].create!(), which will possibly throw a more detailed error.
3. You will eventually end up getting a warning in Rails 4 for defining properties on models as attr_accessible. This is because model security has been delegated to the controller with the accepts_nester_attributes_for stuff.
4. Connection is a very general name for a class. It's possible that the class has already been defined by the rails framework.

Cheers and good luck!